# Using classes form different folder in .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have an old .NET Framework 3.5 project from someone else that I need to get working again. The project has an old .sln file that I used to open it in Visual Studio 2022. The issue is that it uses personal libraries that were located somewhere else. I have downloaded these libraries and copied them to a folder inside the project but they only contain .cs files.

How do you properly add these .cs files so that the compiler will recognize the classes inside the libraries that were used throughout the project?

Here is a screenshot of how the folder structure looks:
[Project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnHm0.png)

I wish to add all the .cs files inside the BumTehnolink folder as libraries.

Comment: Usually you would use a dll for a class library, and then reference that in the project references.  Adding source cs files does not require any reference setup, and will work immediately since they live in the same assembly.  Did you include them in the project (right click the file and in the context menu click the Include option)?

Comment: @hijinxbassist i did not do this exactly but if i right click them i can only click "Exclude From Project", which suggests they are part of the project i guess. However i still get this error whenever i try to import the class. https://imgur.com/a/b9s6ER1 I'm not sure what really this means. Does it require a dll file?

Comment: Do you have the class Baza in a file somewhere?  You probably just need to include the namespace.  `i can only click "Exclude From Project"` Yep, that means they are part of the project.

Comment: Baza class is defined in the /BumTehnolink/Iglavci/Smreka/smreka.cs file. It's under Bum.Iglavci.Smreka namespace. I tried importing the class with "using Bum.iglavci.Smreka" but it doesn't seem to recognize it. It turns out that smreka.cs file itself has some issues with missing libraries. Is it possible that those issues need to be resolved before I can use it to import to somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, those dependencies will need to be resolved for that class to resolve.